# How to wait for JavaScript to finish in playwright

Tags: javascript, puppeteer, playwright

I am testing UI with Playwright and JavaScript. My code find an input element that can sometimes be a drop down, sometimes a text and sometimes a date. To handle this I enter value with 2 steps. First I fill the text and then click on tab key to invoke the JavaScript that formats the value in the element.

```
await page.fill("#myID", inputText); 
await page.keyboard.press('Tab');  // this line trigger the JS

// continue to the next element
```

The problem, it is not waiting for JavaScript to finish. How can I wait for JS to finish before the code continue.

Answer (score 13):

You could wait for some reaction to your click (some page change, or HTTP request made), for example:

- wait for certain element state change https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-locator#locator-wait-for
- wait for a new element to appear on the page (like a dialog open) https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-selector
- wait until a request fired https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-request
- wait until a response received https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-response
- or wait for an event https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-wait-for-event

Answer (score 8):

#### Using the `page.waitFor...` functions

There are a slew of functions that playwright offers for when certain conditions are met that start with `page.waitFor`  (e.g. [`page.waitForFunction`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#pagewaitforfunctionpagefunction-arg-options)).  Probably `page.waitForFunction` is the most versatile, because you can pass a custom function that waits for a specific condition to be met.

#### Alternatively, use a timeout

I think you can use `setTimeout` with `page.evaluate` inside the page context to wait a bit for other JavaScript to run:

```
await page.evaluate(() => {
  // if this doesn't work, you can try to increase 0 to a higher number (i.e. 100)
  return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 0));
});
```

This might be equivalent to [`page.waitForTimeout(0)`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#pagewaitfortimeouttimeout), but I'm not sure. Note that they recommend not to use `page.waitForTimeout` in production.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not good in this case. This pattern happens many times and if I use hardcoded value, the script will be very slow. I need to stop waiting when JS is finished.

Comment: You can try using a timeout of 0, which may work, depending on how the events bubble, or you can abstract it to function that lets you pass a `timeout` argument. If that doesn't work, it's hard to determine when JS is "finished", without explicitly writing code that says that it is done (for example, if you can edit the client code, you could have a custom function called `doneClientSide()`, that you can check for in playwright). I have a feeling you'll have performance issues in general.

Comment: I think waitForFunction may help, though it won't be easy. I need to check. Thanks for that!

Answer (score 0):

**Verify that any one of these objects is visible:**

```
let combinedLocator='Xpath1 | Xpath2 | Xpath3 | XpathN'
await page.locator(combinedLocator).toBeVisible({timeout:5000})
```